# Ignore .git directory in ctrlp.vim

Tags: vim, ctrlp

In my `.vimrc` I have some custom ingores for [ctrlp.vim](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim). There are a few directories I want to ignore that start with a dot: `.git` is a good example. By having `.git` in the ignores, I also ignore individual files like `git.sh`. I only want to ignore `.git`. What am I doing wrong?

```
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = 'node_modules\|DS_Store\|bower_components\|.sass-cache\|.git\|build'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to specify that `.git` is specifically a directory ignore.
From the documentation's example: https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim

```
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = {
  \ 'dir':  '\v[\/]\.(git|hg|svn)$',
  \ 'file': '\v\.(exe|so|dll)$',
  \ 'link': 'some_bad_symbolic_links',
  \ }
```

Comment: I've seen that in the README.md on Github, but when I put it in my .vimrc I get an 'invalid expression' error.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide this information for future reference.

Comment: Actually I spoke too soon on that. So the problem I have now is that not all directories I want to ignore start with a dot.

Comment: You don't need to have dots on all directories that you mention on that field. This is a regular expression just like any other. You can have something like `\vfoo_without_dot\|\.(git|bar)`, for example

Comment: Simple enough. This does what I wanted. `'dir': '\v[\/](\.git|node_modules|\.sass-cache|bower_components|build)$'` Thanks!

Comment: could you please explain the syntax '\v[\/]' ?

Comment: me too， waiting explain about syntax '\v[\/]'

Comment: @HuiWang, @deemstone this is vimscript's "very magic" regexp modifyier, which changes the behaviour of some characters in the context of a regular expression (usually allowing it to be written in simplified form) See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic About `[\/]`, means nothing special: matches any of '\' or '/' (remember directory separator on Windows).

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/649714/can-i-get-the-vim-ctrlp-plugin-to-ignore-a-specific-folder-in-one-project#660318